# Change what navigation bar floating button calls flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, widget

I am writing an application in flutter for one of my courses at university.

[UI of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kWdm.png)

Above is the basic UI of my application. I am trying to change the behaviour of the play button on the navigation bar depending on the widget that is in  the body of the app. I was wondering what the best option is for this ?

I have attempted to remove the button from the navigation bar and make it within the widgets themselves but it does not sit on top of the navigation bar as I want. I have also tried making a method within the navigation bar that detect what page is open and to call different methods from within the page but did not manage to get it working

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of **state management**.

If you are new to it, start [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tm-R7ymwhc).

The best solution would be to use a [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and notify the button whenever a change occurs from the Bottom Nav Bar or in the Body Widget.